# Similarity of diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am looking for an elegant proof of the following:
Let $A,B \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ be diagonalizable matrices, and $P_A, P_B$ their characteristic polynomials. Then:

$A, B$ similar $\Leftrightarrow$ $P_A = P_B$

I am somehow stuck at this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Matrices satisfy their characteristic polynomials. What happens when you substitute a matrix similar to $A$ into $A$'s characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Very nice approach! However I can't think through it. Say A similar to B $\Rightarrow$ $A = S B S^{-1}$. Then I have $P_B(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i A = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i S B S^{-1} = S \left( \sum_{i=1}^n c_i B \right) S^{-1} = S 0 S^{-1} = 0$. So i get $P_A(B) = P_B(A) = 0$. Using the minimal polynomials $M_A$ and $M_B$, I get $M_A|P_B$ and $M_B|P_A$. Also $P_A$ and $P_B$ have the same degree, but I can't see why herby follows $P_A=P_B$?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are similar, then $B=XAX^{-1}$. So
$$
P_B(t)=\det B-t\,I=\det XAX^{-1}-t\,XX^{-1}=\det X(A-t\,I)X^{-1}=\det A-t\,I=P_A(t).
$$

Conversely, if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A=SDS^{-1}$, with $D$ diagonal. Then 
$$
P_A(t)=\det A-t \,I=\det SAS^{-1}-tSS^{-1}=\det S(D-t\,I)S^{-1}\\=\det D-t\,I=(D_{11}-t)\cdots(D_{nn}-t).
$$
So, if $P_A=P_B$, we conclude that $A=SDS^{-1}$, $B=TDT^{-1}$ for the same diagonal matrix $D$, and thus 
$$
B=TDT^{-1}=TS^{-1}AST^{-1}=(TS^{-1})A(TS^{-1})^{-1}.
$$